# chartjs doesn't render dates properly

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs, react-chartjs-2

I made a custom chartjs component in reactjs and want to render dates in xAxes and numbers from -1 to 1 in yAxes but it renders data not in a proper way.
[image: this is the output I get from the component below]

```js
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";

import Chart from "chart.js";

const ChartComponent = ({ data, label, min, max }) => {
    const canvasRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const canvasObj = canvasRef.current;
        const context = canvasObj.getContext("2d");

        new Chart(context, {
            type: "line",
            data: {
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: label,
                        backgroundColor: "transparent",
                        data: data,
                    },
                ],
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [
                        {
                            type: "time",
                            distribution: "linear",
                            time: {
                                unit: "month",
                                displayFormats: {
                                    quarter: "YYYY mm dd",
                                },
                            },
                        },
                    ],
                    yAxes: [
                        {
                            ticks: {
                                suggestedMax: max,
                                suggestedMin: min,
                            },
                        },
                    ],
                },
            },
        });
    }, [data, label, min, max]);

    return <canvas ref={canvasRef}> </canvas>;
};

export default ChartComponent;
```

and I'm passing the data like this to the component

```js
<ChartComponent
    min={-1}
    max={1}
    label="date"
    data={[
        {
            x: "30/03/2018",
            y: 0.1158,
        },
        {
            x: "24/09/2018",
            y: 0.1975,
        },

        {
            x: "23/12/2018",
            y: 0.1913,
        },
        {
            x: "23/03/2019",
            y: 0.2137,
        },
    ]}
/>;
```

I have to metion that I have done the same thing and that is working alright this is example below

```js
<ChartComponent
    min={1270}
    max={1272}
    label=" مساحت دریاچه"
    data={[
        {
            x: "04/02/2017",
            y: 1270.7,
        },

        {
            x: "06/26/2017",
            y: 1270.74,
        },

        {
            x: "09/19/2017",
            y: 1270.31,
        },
        {
            x: "12/18/2017",
            y: 1270.28,
        },
        {
            x: "06/16/2018",
            y: 1270.81,
        },
        {
            x: "09/24/2018",
            y: 1270.27,
        },
        {
            x: "12/23/2018",
            y: 1270.54,
        },
        {
            x: "05/25/2019",
            y: 1271.94,
        },
        {
            x: "06/18/2019",
            y: 1271.84,
        },
        {
            x: "09/19/2019",
            y: 1271.31,
        },
        {
            x: "12/18/2019",
            y: 1271.25,
        },
        {
            x: "03/12/2020",
            y: 1271.48,
        },
        {
            x: "06/25/2020",
            y: 1271.72,
        },
    ]}
/>;
```

any recommendation would be appreciated. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the date strings you provide are not of [ISO 08601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) nor [RFC 2822 Date time format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.3), hence they cannot be [parsed](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) by [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/), which is internally used by Chart.js.

To make it work, you have to define [`xAxes.time.parser: "DD.MM.YYYY"`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#parser).

Please take a look at below runnable code and see how it works. This is pure JavaScript example but it should also work with `react-chartjs-2`.

```js
new Chart("myChart", {
  type: "line",
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      label: 'My Dataset',
      data: [
          { x: "30/03/2018", y: 0.1158 },
          { x: "24/09/2018", y: -0.1975 },
          { x: "23/12/2018", y: 0.1913 },
          { x: "23/03/2019", y: -0.2137 }
        ],
      fill: false
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: "time",
        time: {
          parser: "DD.MM.YYYY",
          unit: "month",
          displayFormats: {
            month: "YYYY MM DD",
          }
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          suggestedMax: 1,
          suggestedMin: -1
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="100"></canvas>
```

> As I already mentioned, Chart.js internally uses Moment.js for the functionality of the [time axis](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html). Therefore make sure to use the [bundled version](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/installation.html#bundled-build) of Chart.js that includes Moment.js in a single file.